# So that vs such that

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

I have never come across "such that" before I started reading a mathematical journal from my country that is published in English. I keep seeing phrases like this :

> Let a, b, c, d be real numbers **such that** a+b+c+d=4

I have a hunch that the correct sentence is

> Let a, b, c, d be real numbers **so that** a+b+c+d=4

but I am not sure. Could you enlighten me, please?

Comment: It seems that they are equivalent..

Answer (score 1):

It is a very common way of describing mathematical objects. You tell the set that the objects are elements of, and then give a restriction in the form of a formula or similar that identifies the particular objects

> Even numbers are integers *n* such that *n=2k* for some integer *k*.

In set notation the colon is read as "such that"

> { n \in **Z** : \exists k\in**Z**, n=2k }

So the use of "such that" is not incorrect. It is the usual way of expressing this type of relation.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand that "such that" is correct in this context. Yet, I wonder, is "so that" all right too?

Answer (score 1):

**Such that** and **so that** actually have a very subtle difference.  From [a thread on this subject](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/difference-between-so-that-and-such-that) in english.stackexchange:

> "Such that" is a description of HOW something is to be done..."So that" is a description of WHY something is to be done.

In your example, the constraint "a+b+c+d=4" tells you **how** you choose a, b, c, and d, so **such that** is appropriate.

You would use **so that** if you're talking about **why** you choose a, b, c, and d.  For example:

> Let a, b, c, d be real numbers **so that** they represent points on a number line.